# same query in snowflake and redshift fetching different results why?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, amazon-redshift

same query in redshift fetching just 18 records but in snowflake it is fetching 27k records. I don't know why... even though the data is same in both databases. what are the reasons behind it
here is the query

```
SELECT CUR.datasource
       , CUR.reqid
       , CUR.respid
       , CUR.caseno
       , CUR.category
       , CUR.topic
       , CUR.contact_type
       , CUR.division
       , CUR.gender
       , CUR.city
       , CUR.region
       , CUR.country
       , CUR.entrydate_loc
       , CUR.entrydate_loc_month
       , CUR.product_name
       , CUR.product_description
       , CUR.req_mode
       , CUR.languages
       , CUR.CODE
       , CUR.CODE_ORIG
       , CUR.dept
       , CUR.inquiry_text
       , CUR.subregion
       , CUR.subregion_amer_la
       , CUR.therapeutic_area
       , CUR.ae_flag
       , CUR.pc_flag
       , CUR.facilitator_flag
       , CUR.resolution
       , CUR.inbound_channel1
       , CUR.inbound_channel2
       , CUR.state_or_region
       , CUR.specialty
       , cur.load_date
 FROM team_incite.gmi_grace_prima_temp CUR
 full outer join team_incite.gmi_grace_translated PREV
  ON CUR.REQID=PREV.REQID AND CUR.RESPID=PREV.RESPID
 WHERE PREV.REQID IS NULL AND PREV.RESPID IS NULL
```

i have checked both the tables in redshift and snowflake and they are returning same count

```
select count(*) from team_incite.gmi_grace_translated;
select count(*) from team_incite.gmi_grace_prima_temp;
```

does anyone know what is missing?

i want to know the root cause

Comment: how sure are you that the data are equal?

Comment: we replicate the data from redshift to snowflake few days ago.

Comment: can you confirm on query level it is nothing wrong and maybe the issue is with data?

Comment: If you are running the same query but getting different results then it must be a data issue. You’ll have to debug it by working through it logically. what happens if you remove the WHERE clause; what happens if you change the join to an INNER or LEFT OUTER?

Comment: Instead of counting rows, you should count distinct values and nulls for each of the columns in your join and where clause

Comment: Additionally also check data types for those columns (redshift vs snowflake)

Comment: Finally found the root cause. The issue was with the data inconsistency across DB. we have migrated the data again in both DBs then query starts fetching correct result.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue is in your ON clause.  In Redshift you cannot test if NULL = NULL, it will never be true.  Since your WHERE clause requires these values to be NULL you cannot every match so you are only getting the OUTER portion in Redshift. I don't know your data so I cannot be sure but this needs to be rewritten to do what you want.  Something like:

```
SELECT CUR.*
FROM team_incite.gmi_grace_prima_temp CUR
full outer join team_incite.gmi_grace_translated PREV
  ON (CUR.REQID=PREV.REQID OR (CUR.REQID IS NULL AND PREV.REQID IS NULL))
 AND (CUR.RESPID=PREV.RESPID OR (CUR.RESPID IS NULL AND PREV.RESPID IS NULL))
WHERE PREV.REQID IS NULL AND PREV.RESPID IS NULL
```